# onItemClickListener how to have a fixed name for each item?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to make a listView that has an editText and when you type something it filters all the contents to the the names with that contains the text the user typed and then you press it to show more information about this name. The filter works fine but the since in the onItemClickListener each case is defined by it's number ex:

```
   case 0:
     ....
     break;
 case 1:
    ....
      break;
    case 2:
    ....
 break;
```

when the user types something and the names get filtered, for example case 45 will become case 0 and it will open the information of the case 0 instead of case 45, so how can I have a fixed name for them like when in the onClick method when you type the id of the button.

Thanks

My code:

```
    final EditText inputSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    list = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gv);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.gridview_design,R.id.name, heartlessNames);
    list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int before,int count){
              updateText();
        }
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count,int after){
          updateText();
        }
        @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
          updateText();
        }
        private void updateText(){
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(inputSearch.getText().toString());

        }
    });

       list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            switch(position){
             case 0:
                   sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), shadow.class));
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.animator.push_left_in, R.animator.push_left_out);
                break;
              case 1:
                  sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), soldier_kh2fm.class));
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.animator.push_left_in, R.animator.push_left_out);
                  break;

            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't really how onItemClicked should be used. You should use onItemClicked in conjunction with your adapter to get the item at that position and use it's data that way.

Comment: @zgc7009 ok but how do I set it in the adapter?

Comment: I am kind of confused by the question, but know that you should probably handle it using the adapters getItem(int position) method. So you are searching and filtering your list? And your list is updating appropriately when you filter? Your list/adapter should be ready to use at that point if so.

Comment: @zgc7009 can you tell me how to use getItem(int position) method

Comment: getItem(int position) will return the item represented in your list view in that position. If you use getItem(0) it will return the first item in the list

Comment: @zgc7009 can you please write the code in an answer, because I am still a beginner at programming and I don't know how to do what you are saying, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a ListView in your Activity, we will call it `listView` and it will likely be setup something like this

```
private ListView listView;
private MyListAdapter adapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
         ...
     }

     ...
}
```

At some point you will build your adapter and set it to your listView (`listView.setAdapter(adapter);`). Notice adapter and listView are class variables so they can be used throughout our entire class. Now your listView should be ready to go. You have told us, `"The filter works fine"`, so I am going to assume at this point you just need to manage handling clicking on an item, that is done with

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        /* THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT TO DO TO GET AN ITEM FROM YOUR LIST */
        String data = dataAdapter.getItem(position);

        // do what you want with your data String
    }

});
```

Where `MyDataObject` is replaced with whatever the type is in your list that your adapter is pulling from. As you can see you use your adapter and the position you clicked on to actually get your data from that position. Your list itself will manage data positions, no need for you to do that.

**EDIT**

Based on your code, I would create a list object that has a reference to what you need, and still let your adapter manage everything.

```
public class ListItemObject{
    private String data;
    private Class clazz;
    private int[] soundSettings;

    public ListItemObject(String data, Class clazz, int[] soundSettings){
        this.data = data;
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.soundSettings = soundSettings;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then change your ArrayAdapter to ArrayAdapter and in your getView method of your adapter do set your values, something like

```
textView.setText(getItem(position).getData());
```

This way when in onItemClickListener you can just do

```
int[] soundSettings = adapter.getItem(position).getSoundSettings();
sp.play(soundId, soundSettiings[0], soundSettings[1], soundSettings[2],
    soundSettings[3], soundSettings[4]);
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), adapter.getItem(position).getClazz()));
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.animator.push_left_in, R.animator.push_left_out);
```

The idea of an adapter/list view is to manage your data in an organized manner. When you try to take control over that you are just asking for trouble. You would have to sync your methods/data with your adapter which is very difficult. Give you adapter all of the data it may need  to represent that position of data and then when you click on that position use the data you get. That is the whole point.

Comment: I'am not sure that I understand, will it help if I add my code and you tell me what to do exactly :)

Comment: @youssefabaza look at my onItemClick method, and look at yours. You need to simply add in the line I have and get rid of your switch statement.

Comment: so I should delete this line "switch(position)" and add this "String data = dataAdapter.getItem(position);"

Comment: @youssefabaza yes. I don't think you are understanding how onItemClick works. You are treating it like onClick, but it isn't. The method onItemClick already gives you the position of an item as it stands in the adapter, there is no reason to try to figure out how the adapter is managing the positions itself, it is right there.

Comment: I got an error for every case "Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "case", assert expected
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to 
  boolean"

Comment: @youssefabaza remove your cases for your switch too. Completely remove your switch statement. I really recommend reading up on some of the fundamentals of Android before you get too far in and find it all crazy confusing.

Comment: I am sorry for making you get nervous, but if I remove all the cases how will I define which button will do what

Comment: @youssefabaza no worries, I'm not nervous, I just know that if you get in over your head with things you will just end up more frustrated than if you understood them before digging in too deep (I have made the mistake in places myself, many devs have). Again, you need to understand how onItemClick works. The adapter contains references to your "buttons", referenced through their position in the adapter. This is handled in getItem(position);. I can't really explain it much better than that. You seem to be missing the idea that the position is handled by your adapter, you don't need to manage it

Comment: I added what my button does can you tell me how to write it properly

Comment: @youssefabaza read my update. I would not take control of the data positioning away from the adapter, instead give your adapter all of your data so that when you click on the item you can pull your data from your adapter and use it as you need it.

Comment: what id the getters and setters

Comment: @youssefabaza the getters and setters are just for your variables. String data has a getter of public String getData(){ return data; } for example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a CursorAdapter as the back end for your list. You can put filtering in directly using a FilterQueryProvider. There are some great examples out there, such as [this one](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html). Something like this is the key:

```
dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
     public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
         return dbHelper.fetchCountriesByName(constraint.toString());
     }
 });

  EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
  myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
    dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
   }
  });
```

Then your dbHelper will do the filtering based on the name, as desired via this syntax.

Comment: This is dependent on a db and a cursor.

Comment: You could do a CursorLoader to put in data, but to be frank, it seems like your project could benifit from a database anyways.

Comment: isn't there another way than making a database and a cursor

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto isn't my project, just pointing out he doesn't have a database (the usual use of a cursor) or a cursor that he is working with so a CursorAdapter would involve reworking his code.